# How to update django models after importing csv if id already exists using django-import-export?

Tags: django, csv, django-import-export

I am using **django-import-export** module for importing csv in my application. However what I want is if I upload the same csv again with some vales changed, it updates the existing values in models rather than adding the same values in new rows. Here is my code:

```
#resources.py:

class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        import_id_fields = ('p_id',)
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = False
```

```
#views.py:

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        product_resource = ProductResource()
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_product = request.FILES['myfile']

        imported_data = dataset.load(new_product.read().decode('utf-8'),format='csv')
        result = product_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run = True)

        if not result.has_errors():
            product_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)
```

```
#models.py:

class Product(models.Model):
    p_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    prop1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    prop2 = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.p_id
```

Comment: Can you please post the solution. I am also having trouble figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exclude=('id')` then remove the id from the file.